# what is "install parameters" in jcmanager?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader

can any body instruct me what is "install parameter" in jcmanager? is it the same PR and LC parameters? what values it accept and what is the difference among different values?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is what is passed as information to the `Applet.install(byte[] param, short paramOffset, byte paramLength)` method. The precise information is in the Global Platform Card specification. It may include GP flags (e.g. default selected), the instance AID and - of course - user parameters.

Comment: That's a pretty minimalistic GUI if it is not enable to generate the parameters.

Comment: sorry dear,but I have not understand yet! would you please explain more clear [for example what values it supports and what's the meaning of each one?] or give me a good link for self study? :) thank you

Comment: I would, but [access to the otherwise free GP specs](http://www.globalplatform.org/specificationform.asp?fid=6281) requires registration.

Comment: No, but a bit of scrounging should get you there.